# web.xml for jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I tried codes with jstl. The exception is

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I am using eclipse. I added `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`. What should I give in `web.xml` now? I don't know what to give in `<taglib>`.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:forEach var = "userName" items = "${name}"> 
<tr> 
<td>${userName}</td>

 </tr>
 </c:forEach>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which servlet container are you using?

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you either downloaded the ancient JSTL 1.0 which has a different URI, or you placed the JAR's in the wrong place (i.e. not in `/WEB-INF/lib` or anywhere in webapp's runtime classpath).

Ensure that you download the right version and put the JAR(s) in `/WEB-INF/lib`. For a webapplication whose `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.5, you need to download just [JSTL 1.2 as jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar). For a Servlet 2.4 webapplication, you need to download [JSTL 1.1 as jstl.jar and standard.jar](http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_taglibs-standard.cgi).

You don't need to extract the JAR's. You also don't need to modify the `web.xml` as some poor online tutorials suggest. Just drop JAR(s) in runtime classpath, declare the taglib in JSP and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make an entry of jstl.jar or standard.jar inside web.xml if the jars are kept in the lib directory inside WEB-INF.
The container by default looks into the lib directory of WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to add the taglib elements to web.xml. The standard & jstl jars are interrogated via the service mechanism in the container.

Make sure the jars are exported with the web-app and located under WEB-INF/lib and you should be fine.